# Modal Parameter passing in the URL

Tags: java, bootstrap-4

Here is my call:

```
1<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Remove</a> 
2<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Remove</a> 
3<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Remove</a>
```

This is in a list. I want to get the correct id(1, 2 or 3) when confirm is pressed. Thanks!

my modal

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>I decline being evaluated for this period.</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <%if(aList!= null && aList.size() > 0) {%><a href="form.jsp?docID=<%=aList.getIdStr()%>&hStatus=S" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Confirm</a><%}%>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: *I want to get the correct id(1, 2 or 3)* and what are these ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Say for example, I have 10 fetched records, each one has a unique identifier and when I click edit/remove on the 5th record, I need to pass that to the docID.

Comment: 1<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Remove</a> 
2<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Remove</a> 
3<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Remove</a>  pass 1 0r 2 or 3 in the front of each row as per selection